# Creating tables based off of SchemaColumn & SchemaTable composite table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wanted to create a new set of tables in a db using a stored procedure and a build table.

The build table includes the following columns and some sample rows:

```
tblNm   colNm       colTyp  colLen  colReq  colWarning  colUni  colComUni
account personID    Decimal NULL    0       0           0       0
account studentNum  String  15      0       0           0       0
```

I was considering using multiple cursors as a form of nested looping, but I cannot figure out how to define the column parameters in the nested procedure because cursors only return one value.

I am considering to build an `alter` statement that parses these values. How could I do this?

Comment: what does the values in `colReq  colWarning  colUni  colComUni` represent?

Comment: colReq = Must not be null
colWarning = whether a custom warning exists in application for data issue that don't fail the validation
colUni = must be unique
colComUni = has a combination of fields value that must  be unique

Comment: Ok, so ColReq 0 is nullable and 1 is not nullable. what about warning, uni and the other columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can solve the problem by using two cursors or one cursor. Two cursors will make the code more readable. One cursor will be more efficient.

**Two cursors**

The code below demonstrates how to use two cursors to iterate through the tables and columns.

```
DECLARE @tblNm VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE cTables CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tblNm
    FROM CompositeSchema
    GROUP BY tblNm
    ORDER BY tblNm
OPEN cTables
FETCH cTables INTO @tblNm
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Processing table '+@tblNm

        -- Start of code to execute for each table

        DECLARE @sqlCreateTable VARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @sqlCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE ['+@tblNm+'] ('

        DECLARE @colNm VARCHAR(MAX),@colTyp VARCHAR(MAX),@colLen INT,@colReq BIT,@colWarning BIT,@colUni BIT,@colComUni BIT
        DECLARE @isFirst BIT
        SET @isFirst = 1
        DECLARE cCols CURSOR FOR
            SELECT colNm,colTyp,colLen,colReq,colWarning,colUni,colComUni
            FROM CompositeSchema
            WHERE tblNm=@tblNm
            ORDER BY colComUni DESC,colNm ASC
        OPEN cCols
        FETCH cCols INTO @colNm,@colTyp,@colLen,@colReq,@colWarning,@colUni,@colComUni
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
            BEGIN
                PRINT 'Processing column ['+@tblNm+'].['+@colNm+']'

                -- Start of code to process each column (simplified!)

                IF @isFirst=0
                    SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+','
                SET @isFirst = 0

                SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+'['+@colNm+'] '+@colTyp
                IF NOT @colLen IS NULL
                    SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+'('+CAST(@colLen AS VARCHAR)+')'

                -- End of code to process each column

                FETCH cCols INTO @colNm,@colTyp,@colLen,@colReq,@colWarning,@colUni,@colComUni
            END
        CLOSE cCols
        DEALLOCATE cCols

        SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+')'
        PRINT @sqlCreateTable

        -- EXEC(@sqlCreateTable)

        -- End of code to execute for each table

        FETCH cTables INTO @tblNm
    END
CLOSE cTables
DEALLOCATE cTables
```

**One cursor**

In this case we use just one cursor. We keep track of what the current table is that we are processing in the @currentTblNm variable. Whenever the variable changes, we create all columns at once.

```
DECLARE @currentTblNm VARCHAR(MAX),@sqlCreateTable VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @currentTblNm = ''

DECLARE @tblNm VARCHAR(MAX),@colNm VARCHAR(MAX),@colTyp VARCHAR(MAX),@colLen INT,@colReq BIT,@colWarning BIT,@colUni BIT,@colComUni BIT
DECLARE @isFirst BIT
SET @isFirst = 1
DECLARE cCols CURSOR FOR
    SELECT tblNm,colNm,colTyp,colLen,colReq,colWarning,colUni,colComUni
    FROM CompositeSchema
    ORDER BY tblNm ASC,colComUni DESC,colNm ASC
OPEN cCols
FETCH cCols INTO @tblNm,@colNm,@colTyp,@colLen,@colReq,@colWarning,@colUni,@colComUni
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        IF @currentTblNm<>@tblNm
            BEGIN
                IF @sqlCreateTable<>''
                    BEGIN
                        SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+')'
                        PRINT @sqlCreateTable
                        --EXEC (@sqlCreateTable)
                    END

                SET @isFirst = 1
                SET @sqlCreateTable = 'CREATE TABLE ['+@tblNm+'] ('
                SET @currentTblNm = @tblNm

                PRINT 'Processing table ['+@tblNm+']'
            END

        -- Start of code to process each column (simplified!)

        IF @isFirst=0
            SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+','
        SET @isFirst = 0

        SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+'['+@colNm+'] '+@colTyp
        IF NOT @colLen IS NULL
            SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+'('+CAST(@colLen AS VARCHAR)+')'

        -- End of code to process each column

        FETCH cCols INTO @tblNm,@colNm,@colTyp,@colLen,@colReq,@colWarning,@colUni,@colComUni
    END
CLOSE cCols
DEALLOCATE cCols

IF @sqlCreateTable<>''
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlCreateTable = @sqlCreateTable+')'
        PRINT @sqlCreateTable

        -- EXEC(@sqlCreateTable)
    END
```

Both pieces of code, Two cursors and One cursor are simplified. The logic to properly create all of the constraints (like primary key, unique constraints, foreign keys etc.), the logic to properly map the column data types, and not to forget, the making the distinction between creating a new table and altering an existing table is beyond the scope of this post.

Worth mentioning is that you could also use declarative SQL code with FOR XML to create the table structure. This is possible and would be able to generate the CREATE TABLE statements with a much better performance. From experience I know that this code will be much harder to maintain and you might run into the limitations of declarative SQL.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually started building a dual cursor for this when someone in another thread started showing me the xml version.  I think the xml version will be better as there is a lot of data to crunch.  But if we hit the limits of SQL then I'll circle back to this.  Thanks so much!